# Comparing work done for two accelerations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, work, potential-energy

Suppose at a time $t_{0}$ a car goes from 0 to 30mph at time $t_{1}$, and then maintains a speed of 30mph until $t_{2}$.  After that minute it accelerates, reaching 60mph at time $t_{3}$.

I want to compare the work done, particularly between $t_{0}$ and $t_{1}$, and between $t_{2}$ and $t_{3}$.  The laws of work that I know are:  $W = \int F \, dx = -\Delta U$.  We don't know the force function and we don't know the potential energy function.  We could use kinetic energy at each point and think that the only forms of energy are potential and kinetic so that they just trade off.

In that case, it would seem that the kinetic energy goes from 0 to $\frac{1}{2}m(30^{2})$ so potential energy is the negative of that and work done is again $\frac{1}{2}m(30^{2})$.  Then going from 30mph to 60mph you go from kinetic energy $\frac{1}{2}m(30^{2})$ to $\frac{1}{2}m(60^{2})$ which is a much higher jump in kinetic, meaning a much bigger change in potential, meaning a much larger work done.  Is that basically right?

Comment: Why are you dragging the potential energy into this? Is your car going uphill or downhill? If is is not, what is the potential energy at any velocity?

Comment: @CuriousOne I don't know what potential is at any velocity. The work laws i wrote are the only ones i know and since force is unknown, I'm just doing what I can with change in potential.

Comment: What is the potential energy when the car is on a flat plane? How does it change, when you are moving it around?

Comment: If you want to make it work with $\int Fdx$ then consider $F=ma=mv\frac{dv}{dx}$. You'll find it all works out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total work done = change in energy. So when you compute the kinetic energy at 30 mph and 60 mph, you find that you needed to do 3x as much work in the second interval.

Note that you do need to convert from mph to m/s if you want to work in SI units…

Leave potential energy out of it. It is not relevant in this situation. Work done = gain in kinetic energy is all you need.